# sed substitution command: do not understand behavior

Tags: sed

My ultimate goal is to use `sed` to automatically convert a Makefile. Right now, I'm trying to get `sed` to change all occurrences of `<string>.o` to `c_<string>.o` where `string` may contain characters, numbers, and underscores. The following command (contained in a script requiring two file names as arguments) does part of the job:

```
sed -E 's/([a-z,A-Z,0-9_]*.o)/c_\1/g' <$1 >$2
```

Operating on the file with contents

```
bye.o
bye1.o
bye_again.o
mycode
-o
%.o
```

I get

```
c_bye.o
c_bye1.o
c_bye_again.o
c_mycode
c_-o
%c_.o
```

But of course the last three lines are incorrect. I need them to remain untouched (so that my target name is unchanged and the Makefile will still be valid).

My questions are:

1. How can I change the `sed` command given above so that the substitution is only active if `<string>` contains at least one character and any string containing `%` is excluded?
2. Why does the `sed` command given above change `mycode` when it does not contain the extension `.o`?

**EDIT:** realspiritual's answer works great on the example file I've given above, but when I try the `sed` command on my actual Makefile, I run into a problem with the dependency section (I know this can be generated automatically by the C compiler, but I need to specify the dependencies manually). There, I get for the following example:

```
hello.o: file1.o file2.o\
        file3.o
```

the output:

```
c_hello.o:c_ file1.oc_ file2.o\
c_      file3.o
```

whereas what I need is:

```
c_hello.o: c_file1.o c_file2.o\
        c_file3.o
```

Answer (score 1):

How to change?

As given below

```
sed -E 's/([^%][a-z,A-Z,0-9_]*\.o)/c_\1/g' <$1 >$2
```

Explanation:

- `"([^%][a-z,A-Z,0-9_]*\.o)"` 1st Capturing group `([^%][a-z,A-Z,0-9_]*\.o)`
- `[^%]` match a single character **not** **present** in the list below `%` the literal character %
- `[a-z,A-Z,0-9_]*` match a single character present in the list below

  - Quantifier:
  - `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  - `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
  - `,` the literal character `,`
  - `A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
  - `,` the literal character `,`
  - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
  - `_` the literal character `_`
  - `\.` matches the character `.` literally
  - `o` matches the character `o` literally (case sensitive)

Why it does not contain .o?

Because the initial . was matching any single character and now it has been escaped `(\)` to be treated as literal

Comment: This works great for the simple example, but with the actual Makefile I run into a problem that I describe in the edited question. It's not clear to me what I need to edit in your `sed` command to get it to work there, too.